# Android studio support library for androidx

Tags: build.gradle, android-support-library, androidx

I want to update the `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'` version for `androidx`. I couldn't find the appropriate migration for it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import your specific packages from this list;

AndroidX Class Mappings:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings

For Support v4:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings#androidsupportv4

For AndroidX add to Gradle, `implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"`.

The "+" at the end of the package in gradle's implementation statement is a regex for the latest stable version available. Number versions can also be used instead of the "+", like; `implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2"`

You can check the latest stable, alpha etc builds with release dates on maven here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.core/core-ktx?repo=google